# How can I show my slide one after one using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple slide with text using Html, CSS, Javascript, where the first slide is displayed to the center of the screen, but I got stuck on how to show the second section-b and the third section-c and then come back to the first one(section-a), I tried to use forEach to loop on each section by giving all the sections the same class name and give a delay to the second and third one but i got stuck again.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const textEL = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
  const two = document.getElementById("two");
  const tree = document.getElementById("tree");
  const four = document.getElementById("four");
  const sectionTExt = document.querySelector(".section-a");
  delay = 500;

  const animation = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[0].style.transform = "translate(0%)"
    }, delay)

    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[1].style.transform = "translate(0%)"
    }, delay * 2)

    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[2].style.transform = "translate(0%)"
    }, delay * 3)

    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[3].style.transform = "translate(0%)"
    }, delay * 4)

    setTimeout(() => {
      sectionTExt.style.opacity = "0"
    }, delay * 5)
  }

  animation();
  // setInterval(animation, delay *6);

});
```

```css
.section-a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  transition: 1.7s ease;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3rem;
  /*Animation*/
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(120%);
}
```

```html
<section class="section-a">
  <p class="text"> Knowledge is Power</p>
  <p class="text"> Power is Knowledge </p>
  <p class="text"> Get Educated </p>
  <p class="text"> Stay Positive </p>
</section>


<section class="section-b">
            <p class="text"> Book</p>
            <p class="text"> We Trade </p>
            <p class="text"> We Are The best </p>
            <p class="text"> Stay Positive </p>
        </section>
```

***What do you think?***

Answer (score 0):

I got the text to show by changing the text color to not match the background color, but I assume there is more you are looking for. Can you clarify what you need? Your question is a bit vague.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const textEL = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
  const two = document.getElementById("two");
  const tree = document.getElementById("tree");
  const four = document.getElementById("four");
  const sectionTExt = document.querySelector(".section-a");
  delay = 1500;

  const animation = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[0].style.transform = "translate(0%)";
      //textEL[0].style.display = "none";

    }, 0)


    //textEL[0].style.display = "none";

    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[0].style.display = "none"
      textEL[1].style.transform = "translate(0%)"
    }, delay)

    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[1].style.display = "none"
      textEL[2].style.transform = "translate(0%)"
    }, delay * 2)

    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[2].style.display = "none"
      textEL[3].style.transform = "translate(0%)"
    }, delay * 3)

    setTimeout(() => {
      textEL[3].style.display = "none"
      sectionTExt.style.opacity = "0"
    }, delay * 4)
  }

  animation();
  // setInterval(animation, delay *6);

});
```

```css
.section-a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  transition: 1.7s ease;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.text {
  color: #555;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3rem;
  /*Animation*/
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(120%);
}
```

```html
<section class="section-a">
  <p class="text"> Knowledge is Power</p>
  <p class="text"> Power is Knowledge </p>
  <p class="text"> Get Educated </p>
  <p class="text"> Stay Positive </p>
</section>


<!-- <section class="section-b">
            <p class="text"> Knowledge is Power</p>
            <p class="text"> Power is Knowledge </p>
            <p class="text"> Get Educated </p>
            <p class="text"> Stay Positive </p>
        </section> -->
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I got too Tob, but What I want exactly is to display section-b after section-a  is faded,

Comment: Thank you so much, but what I want exactly is that section-a as a parent should be displayed first with all its childrens, then the section-b as parent element should be displayed with all its childrens as well.